# 64 bit version of vspdctl.dll

Tags: visual-studio, dll, 64-bit, platform, virtual-serial-port

I am creating an application on VS2013 which makes use of vspdctl.dll to create virtual serial port pair. This virtual port is used to communicate with other application running on my PC.

.exe file has been successfully created when I compile/link using Platform=win32 configuration and virtual port creation works fine.
NOTE: My machine is x64

When I change the platform=x64, my exe is created again without any problems but remains unable to load the dll. It gives me a feeling that vspdctl.dll is a 32 bit library.

But I intend to make use of other 64 bit libraries in the code that is why I also want vspdctl.dll to be implemented in 64 bit application. Is there any 64 bit version of vspdctl.dll or how can I implement 32 bit dll in 64 bit application.

Any help will greatly be appreciated.
Thanks

Here is my code for loading CreateVSPair function of dll

```
char CreateVSPair(char *Port1, char *Port2) {
OSVERSIONINFO VersionInfo;
HINSTANCE libInst;
libInst = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\AK47 Data\\Softwares\\SP monitor\\vspdctl.dll");
if (!libInst)
{
    libInst = LoadLibrary(L"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\\vspdctl.dll");
    if (!libInst)
        return -10; /* Couldn't load library */
}
/* Substitute the typedefs above for functions other than CreatePairFn */
std::string s("CreatePair");
CreatePairFn CreatePair = (CreatePairFn)GetProcAddress(libInst, s.c_str());
if (CreatePair == 0) return -20; /* Couldn`t find function */
bool returnvalue = CreatePair(Port1, Port2); /* For example, Port1 = "COM5" and Port2 = "COM6" */
FreeLibrary(libInst);
return returnvalue;
```

};

Comment: Use property error handling, call GetLastError() to obtain the reason why LoadLibrary() failed.  And use a telephone, call the vendor for support.

Answer (score 0):

There is vspdctl64.dll available which I did not notice before.

Comment: Hi, I add this dll library in QT prj and find symol "CreatePair" but cant make that `bool CreateVSPair(char *Port1, char *Port2) {
    QLibrary lib("libs\\vspdctl.dll");
    lib.load();
    if(!lib.isLoaded()) qDebug() << "hi"+lib.errorString();
    if(lib.isLibrary("libs\\vspdctl.dll")) qDebug() << "it is library";

    CreatePairFn CreatePair=(CreatePairFn)lib.resolve("CreatePair");
    if (CreatePair==0) {
        return false;
    }
    bool v = CreatePair(Port1, Port2); 
    return v;
};void MainWindow::clicked()
{
    CreateVSPair( "COM1", "COM2");
}`